# When doing react server-side, how do I use imported other file types like Webpack?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, reactjs

When doing server-side rendering of JSX files, it won't read in files like Webpack does so I have to make adjustments so it actually does what I want.

For example, I cannot read in files like this:

```js
import './assets/styl/site'
```

Node.js doesn't have Webpack's loaders so it doesn't know how to read a `.styl` or `.cjsx` file.

My node app is run off of CoffeeScript so I had to use a workaround to get it reading `.jsx` using Babel in a file I'm requiring into my CoffeeScript:

```js
//  enable runtime transpilation to use ES6/7 in node

var fs = require('fs');

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc');
var config;

try {
    config = JSON.parse(babelrc);
} catch (err) {
    console.error('==>     ERROR: Error parsing your .babelrc.');
    console.error(err);
}

require('babel-core/register')(config);
```

I think I'm fundamentally getting something wrong w/ server-side rendering, but from all examples, this seems to be the way to do it. I question why Webpack loaders should be used at all client-side as they don't work server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog series explaining how to use webpack on the node side:
http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I

Comment: I checked out this article after you posted about it. It is probably the best I've read so far, but maybe this is a bigger WebPack issue. Even when building for `target: node`, it still complains about window not existing Node-side and thus, not working. I don't know where that's being defined as I commented it outta my own code (might've missed it though).